How to handle scheduled triggers when two instances of Azure Data factory are connected to the same azure devops github repository?
I have two ADF instances running in two different tenants. I need a few pipelines to get triggered from Tenant A and few from Tenant B instance. But looks like all the pipelines re getting triggered only from Tenant A ADF instance. How to handle this?

By the pipelines that are not triggered, do you mean the pipelines in your Azure DevOps organization or the pipelines in your Data Factory?

in the data factory instance in Tenant B
